# Backbone: throttle a collection filter event on a View

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

In my app I have a view displayed as a table which contains a collection fetched from the server. I want the user to be able to filter this collection writing a search string in a text box.

Problem is that the keyup event fire for every keystroke, and I want to avoid this to not overload the server with useless requests. So I thought to use the underscore's throttle function but I can't implement it in a working way.

```
events: {
    'keyup #filter' : 'filter_collection'
}

filter_collection: function(e) {
    var el, throttled, value;

    el = e.currentTarget;
    value = $(el).val();
    this.collection.server_api.filter = value;
    throttled = _.throttle(_.bind(this.update_collection, this), 5000);
    throttled();
}

update_collection: function() {
    var promise, self;

    self = this;
    promise = this.collection.fetch();
    $.when(promise).then(function() {
      self.collection.pager();
    });
}
```

In this way the update_collection function is called for every keystroke, as it was before without `throttle`. I tried also with `debounce` but all the requests will simply fire after the waiting time.
What I'm missing?

Any help is appreciated, thank!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function called each time a *keyup* event occurs is `filter_collection` which is not itself throttled, the one you create inside is immediately called and discarded.

You should bind your event to a throttled function:

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'keyup #filter' : 'filter_collection'
    },

    filter_collection: _.throttle(function(e) {
        var el, throttled, value;

        el = e.currentTarget;
        value = $(el).val();

        this.update_collection(value);
    }, 5000),

    update_collection: function(val) {
        var promise, self;
        self = this;
        promise = this.collection.fetch();
        $.when(promise).then(function() {
          console.log('fetched '+val);
        });
    }
});
```

You could of course use [`_.debounce`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) if you prefer. And see http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/zWrgW/ for a demo

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer :) Also debounce seems to work way better!

Answer (score 0):

You could also bind to the change event rather than keyup.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, however change didn't fire, at least on Firefox. Anyway the event "input" does but I fear it's not compatible with old browsers...